# using --onefile for pyinstaller does not create a single executable, instead it keeps creating a directory

Tags: python, command, exe, pyinstaller

I have a python script and a python spec file. The spec file contains some code which adds a couple of directories needed for my script. When i do

```
pyinstaller script.spec script.py
```

it creates a directory like normal. However when i do

```
pyinstaller --onefile script.spec script.py
```

it dosent create a single executable, instead it does the same thing as if i didnt include it.

is it something to do with my command line or is it something with the spec file?

spec file code:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['memrise.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\blahblahpath\\memrise'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\blahblahpath\\memrise\\chromedriver_win32\\','.\\selenium\\webdriver\\')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='memrise',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               Tree('C:\\Users\\blahblahpath\\memrise\\assets', prefix='assets\\'),
               Tree('C:\\Users\\blahblahpath\\langdetect', prefix='langdetect\\'),
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='memrise')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct.

What you need to do is to check the **dict** file,

there should be a lot of files inside if you don't use --onefile

but there should only be one .exe file inside if you use.

Comment: Ok, my dict file contains stuff in the `data=[]` which simply adds an exe to a directory  and also contains a `Tree()` which makes a directory. Is one of those two the problem? I can add my code if you want.

Comment: I updated the post with the spec file code. I think the issue is to do with me adding directories. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: hmm, you can try finding help (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whenthingsgowrong.html) here.